# How can I display a 3dmodel that is stored in Firebase storage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, three.js

I'm creating a React web app that helps share 3d models, and I run into this problem. When I try to render a 3dmodel file (.obj, .gltf...) using the reference download link, I used react-three library.

I realized that it is not possible to render 3d models from a URL, the file has to be downloaded locally

I would like to know the best solution if I want to display the models on the browser without having to download them on the client side

`

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { collection, getDoc, doc, onSnapshot } from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase-config";
import { AuthContext } from "../context/AuthContext";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { useGLTF } from "@react-three/drei";

const Preview = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [docData, setDocData] = useState(null);
  const { currentUser } = useContext(AuthContext);
 
//loading the model

  function Model(props) {
    const { scene } = useGLTF(docData.file);
    return <primitive object={scene} {...props} />;
  }
//fetching the data
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchDocData = async () => {
      try {
        const userUid = currentUser.uid;
        const docRef = doc(db, "users", userUid, "submissions", id);
        const docSnapshot = await getDoc(docRef);
        if (docSnapshot.exists()) {
          setDocData(docSnapshot.data());
        } else {
          console.log("Document does not exist.");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Error fetching document:", error);
      }
    };

    fetchDocData();
  }, [id]);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Preview</h2>
      {docData && (
        <div>
          <p>file: {docData.file}</p>
          <p>Name: {docData.name}</p>
          <Canvas>
            <Model scale={0.01} />
          </Canvas>
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Preview;
```

the docData.file would look something like this "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/...."

Comment: Are you asking how to download a file from Firebase Storage? If so, this would be a good place to start: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files

Comment: not quite, i meant showcasing the 3dmodel without having to download it locally, in threejs the useGLTF() functions allows you to load a 3d object but it has to take in a path to that file 
useGLTF('path/to/file.gltf')   
what I'm trying to achieve is to load the model that is stored in firebase storage which is referred to by a link not a path 

thanks for the feedback.

Comment: I get the use-case, but it's more likely we can help (or you can find your own solution) if you bring it back to the API calls. If I read it correctly, you're asking [how to show a 3d model from memory in three.js](https://www.google.com/search?q=three.js+render+3d+model+from+memory)